# Image pixel values are getting changed when rendered on screen

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, comparison

I have an image tinytray0.png
[image: tinytray0]

When it is rendered on screen through the exe file, I capture the image and store it as newtray.png 
[image]

It is the same image and dimensions are the same. When I try to compare the images pixel by pixel by means of the following code -

```
if (img2.Width == img1.Width && img2.Height == img1.Height)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < img2.Width; i++)
     {
           for (int j = 0; j < img2.Height; j++)
           {
               var firstPixel = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
               var secondPixel = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
               if (firstPixel != secondPixel)
               {
                   imgeq = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
      }
 }
 else
 {
     imgeq = false;
 }
```

The image dimensions and resolutions are the same, but pixel values are different and I'm getting imgeq as false.

Comment: Those two images are from different sources, why do you expect them to be equivalent pixel by pixel, generally speaking never compare two images pixel by pixel. This is even worse than comparing two floats bit by bit.

Comment: Then how do I compare these 2 images so that I get result as true?

Comment: Do you save the new png with the same color depth as the original?

Comment: How do I save it with the same color depth? I saved it using this code - 
Bitmap tray = new Bitmap(NPDVariableMap.NPDUITrayImage.CaptureImage());
tray.Save(@"E:\IGHS Automation\MAIN\Tesco.Instore.Automation.UITest\NPDImages\newtray.png");

Comment: Even with the same depth, you won't get the same results.

Comment: Check what the differences are in more detail and whence they come  One reason would be the alpha channel; the png may have it but the screen capture will not. Also diffenrent color depths.  A possible solution will depend on the level of exactness you need. You could reduce imformation before you compare each pixel. For example you could set alpha to 255 for each pixel and the rg&b channels to something like r=r/64 etc.. Also you could set a level for how many pixel you allow to differ, like 5% or 10%. The best solution will come to you once you have understood the reason for the differences.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your images I found that it is just as I thought: The original has rounded corners with Alpha=0 and the capture has a solid Color of white. So you could change your code like this:

```
if (img2.Width == img1.Width && img2.Height == img1.Height)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < img2.Width; i++)
     {
           for (int j = 0; j < img2.Height; j++)
           {
               var firstPixel = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
               var secondPixel = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();

               // skip all non opaque pixels!
               if (img2.GetPixel(i, j).A != 255) continue;  
               if (firstPixel != secondPixel)
               {
                   imgeq = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
      }
 }
 else
 {
     imgeq = false;
 }
```

This should work for the examples you posted.
But my other remarks still apply: Reducing information by shifting the channels right and also setting an accepted level of differences will make the comparison more reliable.

**But**: In addition you must consider that not all **deployment machines** may have them means to display the images without strechting or blurring them!

**Edit**: I overlooked your ToString() and have changed the code. A is the alpha channel of an ARGB color..

**Note**: you must decide which is the png pixel; your numbering is a bit mixed up.

Comment: What is A? I tried implementing as you said and I'm getting an error "'string' does not contain a definition for 'A' and no extension method 'A' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"